# When going through some if and elif clauses it just stops in one?

Tags: python, if-statement

Hello I am doing a python homework. Now I'm in secondary and I'm pretty bad at python as I haven't been exposed to it for long. So I have a noobish question regarding the overall workings of python.

```
choice = input("Pick a letter that you think is in the word: ") 
if choice in right or choice in wrong or choice not in abc:
    print("Oops! This letter has already been guessed or it's not a letter at all!")
    return
elif choice == realone:
    one = choice
    right.append(choice)
elif choice == realtwo:
    two = choice
    right.append(choice)
elif choice == realthree:
    three = choice
    right.append(choice)
elif choice == realfour:
    four = choice
    right.append(choice)
elif choice == realfive:
    five = choice
    right.append(choice)
elif choice == realsix:
    six = choice
    right.append(choice)
else:
    guesses = guesses - 1
    wrong.append(choice)
```

So lemme explain it all. This is a part of my Hangman code. Choice is a character the player guesses. real(somenumber) variable is what the real letter of the word is. The numbers one two three without the real in front is for displaying that you got the character correct. However when a word gets picked that has characters that are repeated (adduct) it kind of fails. So when I type in d, it only displays one of the d's in adduct (the first one). I think it goes through the if elif clauses and when it falls into one it doesn't go further. Anyone got any suggestions? Explain if possible :)

Comment: When a particular condition is satisfied, and it falls into a particular elif clause, WHY should it go further? That is the whole point of if-elif clauses. If you want it to go further, just use ifs and not elifs.

Comment: Why in the world are you using separate variables for the letters of the word? Use a list. Then you won't need the `if` statements at all.

Comment: I need to have them seperate because then I'll know which character the person guessed. It's no good if they get it correct and I don't even know which character they got right.

Comment: @HavanAgrawal Thanks for the if clauses suggestion. You're a live saver mate